# (Query) Number of tries before the first correct solution

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the table **solution** with: id, user_id, problem_id correct, date, tries

where **correct** can be true or false

**date** is the date the solution was saved

and **tries** is the number of times the user have submitted a solution

```
user_id  problem_id  tries correct
-------  ----------  ----- --------
1        1           1     true
1        2           1     false
1        2           2     false
1        2           3     false
1        3           1     false
1        3           2     false
1        3           3     true
1        3           4     false
```

I need to get the user's number of tries before the first correct solution,
So I've tried this:

```
SELECT problem_id, tries FROM solution
where user_id= and correct = true
group by problem_id order by date;
```

This gives me the number of tries until the first correct solution, but only for the solutions that were at least once correct.

```
problem_id  tries 
----------  ----- 
1           1    
3           3
```

I also need to see the number of tries even if the user has never had a correct solution.
How can I get these two results together?

```
problem_id  tries 
----------  ----- 
1           1
2           3    
3           3
```

Comment: Can you post a small sample of rows from the table? It is not exactly obvious to me whether you have multiple rows per `problem_id, user_id`, or _one_ row per `problem_id, user_id`.

Comment: And if it is one row per, does `tries` include the correct solution, or only the incorrect ones? In other words, if a user tries 4 times and gets the right solution on the 4th, does `tries = 3` or `tries = 4`?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I forgot about problem_id. I posted a small sample of rows from the table.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski tries=4

Comment: Do you need to filter out correct/incorrect tries AFTER first correct try? Because if you dont - then query is a simple select problem_id, max(tries) group by problem_id.

Comment: @Alexander I need #times the solution was incorrect, before the first time it was correct. (After a user submit a correct solution he/she can submit again, and it can be correct ou incorrect again. That is why it has to be just before the first correct, and I can not use max(tries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly using a sub query (not tested):-

```
SELECT problem_id, IF(b.user_id IS NULL, 0, COUNT(*))
FROM solution a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, problem_id, MIN(date) AS min_date
    FROM solution
    WHERE correct = true
    GROUP BY user_id, problem_id
) b
ON a.problem_id = b.problem_id
AND a.user_id = b.user_id
AND a.date < b.min_date
WHERE a.user_id = ?
GROUP BY problem_id
```

EDIT - Having played with the test data I think I may have a solution. Not sure if there are any edge cases it fails on though:-

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.problem_id, SUM(IF(b.user_id IS NULL OR a.date <= b.min_date, 1, 0))
FROM solution a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT user_id, problem_id, MIN(date) AS min_date
    FROM solution
    WHERE correct = 'true'
    GROUP BY user_id, problem_id
) b
ON a.problem_id = b.problem_id
AND a.user_id = b.user_id
GROUP BY a.user_id, problem_id
```

This has a sub query to find the lowest date with a correct solution for a user problem and joins that against the list of solutions. It the does a SUM of 1 or 0, with a row counting as 1 if there is no correct solution, or if there is a correct solution and the date of that correct solution is greater or equal this this solutions date.

SQL fiddle for it here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f48e11/1

Comment: Having a play now you have put up some test data. This is an interesting problem.

Comment: I confess I did not understant your query. Also, when I try it I get all the users (I think). I just need for one in specific. I'm going to search user by user.

Comment: You can just add a WHERE clause for user_id to limit it to a single user. If you want more idea of how it works then take a copy of it, knock the `GROUP BY a.user_id, problem_id` from the bottom and change `SUM(IF(b.user_id IS NULL OR a.date <= b.min_date, 1, 0))` to `IF(b.user_id IS NULL OR a.date <= b.min_date, 1, 0)` . This should show you the intermediate rows and what it sums up to get the count.

Comment: Yes... thank you for put your thoughts on this. I going to try to understant your query. It works !

Answer (score 0):

If the query you mention gets you what you want for "Correct" answers, to get "Incorrect" numbers, just UNION your query with an effective duplicate of itself adjusting the correct = true to a correct = false predicate.

Comment: But with correct = false I going to get the first time a solution was incorrect. I need the #time it was incorrect, before it was correct (for the first time).